# Understanding pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I know this may seem simple, but it's not making sense to me.

What I need to do: 
I need to prompt for account balance A in one function, return to main, prompt for account balance B in another function, return to main, and then I need to pass both variables into another function, compare which is larger, and set my pointer to either balanceA or balanceB. I need to then manipulate the account balance in another function by manipulating the pointer.

My understanding of what happens:
by passing both variables into a function, and setting a pointer to the larger account, I can manipulate the pointer, and in turn it will manipulate the value of either balanceA or balanceB, whichever is larger (simple IF)

My understanding (or lack thereof) of the syntax:
I need to pass the two account variables by reference and in my compare function, I need to create a new pointer variable, which will be set equal to the account balance that is higher.

My main question:
Where do I declare my pointer, and what is the proper syntax to do so. Where do all of my &'s and *'s go?

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float getBalanceA();
float getBalanceB();

int main()
{
   float balanceA = getBalanceA();
   float balanceB = getBalanceB();

   return 0;
}

float getBalanceA()
{
   float balanceA = 0;

   cout << "What is Sam's balance? ";
   cin >> balanceA;

   return balanceA;
}

float getBalanceB()
{
   float balanceB = 0;

   cout << "What is Sue's balance? ";
   cin >> balanceB;

   return balanceB;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` (reference operator) to create a pointer to a variable, use `*` (dereference operator) to obtain the value referenced by a given pointer.

You are looking for something like the following:

```
float* getLarger(float* a, float* b)
{
    if (*a > *b) // dereference pointers to compare the values
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}

int main()
{
    float balanceA = getBalanceA();
    float balanceB = getBalanceB();
    float* largerBalance = getLarger(&balanceA, &balanceB); // obtain pointers to balanceA/balanceB and pass them to the getLarger functoin
    *largerBalance += 1; // manipulate the larger balance by dereferencing it
    cout << "Sam's balance: " << balanceA << endl;
    cout << "Sue's balance: " << balanceB << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for explaining the difference between the & and the * operators. That was a complete lightbulb moment, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, since you mentioned pass-by-reference, perhaps a more correct example would be using `float&` instead of `float*` (the `*` and `&` here are not (de)reference operators, but type modifiers used to indicate a pointer-to-type and reference-to-type). References are basically pointers with more natural syntax (you use them like normal variables), but you can't change the variable they refer to after setting it initially.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (my code works now so I don't think I am) but I need to pass a pointer without the * operator, and then within the function as I manipulate my data, I want to include the * operator to get at the actual data, and not the pointer. Thanks again for helping me understand this concept.